# How do I add arguments for a function used as an input to another function in R?

Tags: r, function

I have a global function of roughly the form:

```
demo_fcn <- function(f, x1,x2){
  r = x1 - x2 
  return(f(r))
}
```

I want to create this function in a general way so that users can add their own `f` with their own custom inputs, so long as there is an input slot for `r`. Say we take `f` to be the following function

```
f <- function(input, factor){
   out = input^factor
   return(out)
}
```

In this case, `input = r`, so that the user is able to call

```
demo_fcn(f(factor=2),x1=2,x2=3)
```

I get the error

```
Error in f(factor = 2) : argument "input" is missing, with no default
```

The desired outcome here should be the following code running

```
r = 2-3
f(input=r, factor=2)
```

The end goal is to implement this in a more complicated function, with multiple arguments for both `demo_fcn` and `f`

```
demo_fcn <- function(f, x1,x2){
  r1 = x1 - x2
  r2 = x1+x2 
  return(f(r1,r2))
}
f <- function(input1, input2, factor1,factor2){
   out = input^factor1 + input2^factor2
   return(out)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to pass a function (not a function *call*), and use `...` in the top function to pass additional arguments.

```r
demo_fcn <- function(f, x1, x2, ...) {
  r = x1 - x2
  f(r, ...)
}

f <- function(input, factor){
 out = input^factor
 out
}

demo_fcn(f, x1=2, x2=5, factor=2)
# [1] 9
```

If you want to have multiple such functions, then you can do:

```r
demo_fcn <- function(f1, f2, x1, x2, f1opts = NULL) {
  r = x1 - x2
  do.call(f, c(list(r), f1opts))
}
demo_fcn(f, x1=2, x2=5, f1opts=list(factor=2))
```

---

Yet another alternative, taking from `curve`, which may match more closely what you're hoping for.

```r
demo_fcn <- function(expr, x1, x2, xname = "x") {
  r = x1 - x2
  sexpr <- substitute(expr)
  if (is.name(sexpr)) {
    expr <- call(as.character(sexpr), as.name(xname))
  } else {
    if (!((is.call(sexpr) || is.expression(sexpr)) && xname %in%
            all.vars(sexpr)))
      stop(gettextf("'expr' must be a function, or a call or an expression containing '%s'",
                    xname), domain = NA)
    expr <- sexpr
  }
  ll <- list(x = r)
  names(ll) <- xname
  eval(expr, envir = ll, enclos = parent.frame())
}

demo_fcn(f(x, factor=2), x1=2, x2=5)
# [1] 9
```

See `?curve` for more explanation of `xname=`, but in short: use `x` in your call to `f(.)` though it does not use any object named `x` in the local or other environment, *it is just a placeholder*. If you prefer, you can change to `xname="input"` and `demo_fcn(f(input,factor=2),...)` for the same effect, but realize that in that call, `input` is still a placeholder, not a reference to an object.

Comment: Is there any way to link factor directly to f in the final function call? In case I want to expand it to include multiple functions

Comment: See my edit for two alternatives.